# Pandas resampler changes datetime?

Tags: python, pandas

Initial data:

```
df.head()
df.tail()
```

ouput:

```
                                  value
ts                                     
2017-09-20 21:00:45.514847+00:00  -60.0
2017-09-20 21:01:29.169977+00:00  -60.0
2017-09-20 21:02:13.694557+00:00  -60.0
2017-09-20 21:02:57.954950+00:00  -60.0
2017-09-20 21:03:40.615305+00:00  -60.0
                                  value
...
ts                                     
2017-09-21 20:56:27.126042+00:00  -60.0
2017-09-21 20:57:11.993958+00:00  -60.0
2017-09-21 20:57:55.010927+00:00  -60.0
2017-09-21 20:58:40.413179+00:00  -60.0
2017-09-21 20:59:25.451698+00:00  -60.0
```

As you can see the data is timestamp(+03:00) and value for 1 day = 24H

the result to resample data with different time periods:

```
resample_params = [u'1H', u'2H', u'4H', u'6H', u'8H', u'12H',]
```

Lets do it:

```
for resample_rule in resample_params:
    r = df1.resample(resample_rule, closed='right', label='left', base=1)
    # mean-median-count
    result = r.agg(['mean', 'median', 'count', 'std', 'sem', 'mad',])
    result.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    print result.value['count'], '\nlen =', len(result.value['count']), 'sum =', sum(result.value['count'])
```

Output:

```
ts
2017-09-20 21:00:00+00:00    82
2017-09-20 22:00:00+00:00    82
2017-09-20 23:00:00+00:00    83
2017-09-21 00:00:00+00:00    83
2017-09-21 01:00:00+00:00    83
Freq: H, Name: count, dtype: int64 
len = 24 sum = 1977
ts
2017-09-20 21:00:00+00:00    164
2017-09-20 23:00:00+00:00    166
2017-09-21 01:00:00+00:00    166
2017-09-21 03:00:00+00:00    166
2017-09-21 05:00:00+00:00    165
Freq: 2H, Name: count, dtype: int64 
len = 12 sum = 1977
ts
2017-09-20 21:00:00+00:00    330
2017-09-21 01:00:00+00:00    332
2017-09-21 05:00:00+00:00    328
2017-09-21 09:00:00+00:00    330
2017-09-21 13:00:00+00:00    329
Freq: 4H, Name: count, dtype: int64 
len = 6 sum = 1977
ts
2017-09-20 19:00:00+00:00    330
2017-09-21 01:00:00+00:00    497
2017-09-21 07:00:00+00:00    493
2017-09-21 13:00:00+00:00    493
2017-09-21 19:00:00+00:00    164
Freq: 6H, Name: count, dtype: int64 
len = 5 sum = 1977
ts
2017-09-20 17:00:00+00:00    330
2017-09-21 01:00:00+00:00    660
2017-09-21 09:00:00+00:00    659
2017-09-21 17:00:00+00:00    328
Freq: 8H, Name: count, dtype: int64 
len = 4 sum = 1977
ts
2017-09-20 13:00:00+00:00    330
2017-09-21 01:00:00+00:00    990
2017-09-21 13:00:00+00:00    657
Freq: 12H, Name: count, dtype: int64 
len = 3 sum = 1977
```

periods = `u'1H', u'2H', u'4H'`are OK

but  `u'6H', u'8H', u'12H'` **gives len+1 and change timestamp** (look at the first row of each df)

i tried different **base**, **closed** and **label** arguments and [resample rules](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)

How to get proper resample for more than 4H?

Answer (score 1):

After further research of [resample](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html?highlight=resample#pandas.DataFrame.resample) method i get that **base is int** can be negative!!!
**base=-3** works great for me!

Output:

```
ts
2017-09-20 21:00:00+00:00    82
2017-09-20 22:00:00+00:00    82
2017-09-20 23:00:00+00:00    83
2017-09-21 00:00:00+00:00    83
2017-09-21 01:00:00+00:00    83
Freq: H, Name: count, dtype: int64 
len = 24 sum = 1977
ts
2017-09-20 21:00:00+00:00    164
2017-09-20 23:00:00+00:00    166
2017-09-21 01:00:00+00:00    166
2017-09-21 03:00:00+00:00    166
2017-09-21 05:00:00+00:00    165
Freq: 2H, Name: count, dtype: int64 
len = 12 sum = 1977
ts
2017-09-20 21:00:00+00:00    330
2017-09-21 01:00:00+00:00    332
2017-09-21 05:00:00+00:00    328
2017-09-21 09:00:00+00:00    330
2017-09-21 13:00:00+00:00    329
Freq: 4H, Name: count, dtype: int64 
len = 6 sum = 1977
ts
2017-09-20 21:00:00+00:00    496
2017-09-21 03:00:00+00:00    494
2017-09-21 09:00:00+00:00    495
2017-09-21 15:00:00+00:00    492
Freq: 6H, Name: count, dtype: int64 
len = 4 sum = 1977
ts
2017-09-20 21:00:00+00:00    662
2017-09-21 05:00:00+00:00    658
2017-09-21 13:00:00+00:00    657
Freq: 8H, Name: count, dtype: int64 
len = 3 sum = 1977
ts
2017-09-20 21:00:00+00:00    990
2017-09-21 09:00:00+00:00    987
Freq: 12H, Name: count, dtype: int64 
len = 2 sum = 1977
ts
2017-09-20 21:00:00+00:00    1977
Freq: 24H, Name: count, dtype: int64 
len = 1 sum = 1977
```